# how to make excel treat cells with function as false or 0

Tags: excel-formula

Is it possible to have a cell with a formula or “” treat like it is a blank cell in excel?

I’m working with fairly big datasets containing several treatment, observations and sampling events. I often have several formula like =IF(A2;>5;A2;””) to sort the data after some criteria, for example:

Is more than 5 specimens of species A present after in treatments 1, 2,3 and 4 . If it is, is species B, C and D present and how many of each species B, C, D are present. If a species is missing I want to have empty/blank cell, that’s way the “” in the formula, to easily see which are present and not.

If I then use SUM on each line for species B, C and D to get the total per line I can get a 0 when all tree cells are blank, so if I make a graph it will be a data point but I want it to skip that line as there are no specimens in that sample. I have tried with =IF(OR(B2;C2;D2)=””;””;SUM(B2:D2) but it don’t work. It can also happened if you have forumlas then SUM.

Grateful for help
/jocke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula I believe you want is:

```
=IF(OR(B2="",C2="",D2=""),"",SUM(B2:D2))
```

Comment: Hi Scott. It worked and it worked with a =IF(AND(B2="";…..) as well, which I needed later. Thanks you so very much for the help.
Cheers, Jocke